# Chapel - Problems With Multilocale Configuration of GASNET MPI substrate

Tags: mpi, chapel, gasnet

I have a forall code with distributed iterators in Chapel and I'm trying to run it on a Cluster.

The code runs perfectly when using the UDP conduit.

Now, I'm trying to use the portable MPI as an internal Layer - with no success.

Here is my configuration:

```
export CHPL_TASKS=qthreads

export CHPL_COMM=gasnet

export CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=mpi

export CHPL_LAUNCHER=gasnetrun_mpi
```

with only this configuration only one node was used. Looking at Gasnet documentation, I added:

```
export GASNET_NODEFILE="$(pwd)"/nodes

export MPIRUN_CMD='mpirun -np %N -machinefile %H %C'
```

(these details are missing in the official documentation).

Ok, now I can run Chapel code using MPI. BUT:

1) Each node has 32 cores. If I put `hello6 -nl x`, x < 33, all processes are executed by the first locale.

1.1) I would like to run `hello6 -nl 4`, so each node would say hello from locale x, adress x.address.

2) Looks like Chapel uses the `$OAR_NODEFILE` (maybe another) to create the Locales vector, because this `OAR_NODEFILE` has one entry per core for each node.

3) However, even if I change manually both `$GASNET_NODEFILE` and `$OAR_NODEFILE` the Locale vector still contains one entry per core for each CPU node.

4) In the cluster I have access, I run mpi codes like this: `mpirun -machinefile $OAR_NODEFILE ~/program`. However, GASNET requires the syntax of the last variable exported.

Can anyone help me configuring the runtime for executing my code on multiple Locales?

Best regards,

Tiago Carneiro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Chapel 1.18 release and Open MPI (let me know if that's not true.) There was a bug in Chapel 1.18 and earlier where when using Open MPI all Chapel instances were packed onto a single node first. This has been fixed on master (https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/pull/11546) and the fix will be included in the 1.19 release.

You could try using git master, or you might be able to set `MPIRUN_CMD="mpirun --bind-to none --map-by ppr:1:node -np %N %P %A"` as a workaround.

Comment: Hello Elliot, Thank you. I'm now able to run my multilocale experiments using MPI. However, I had to make the following modifications to the `MPIRUN_CMD='mpirun --bind-to none --map-by ppr:1:node -np %N -machinefile %H %C'`. One thing I would like to point out is that the official documentation gives no info on how to set up the portable MPI conduit. The only info given -  `GASNET_LAUNCHER=mpirun` - results in compilation errors when making Chapel. Morever,  the need for exporting `MPIRUN_CMD` and `GASNET_NODEFILE` is also missing. Thank you again!

Comment: Good point -- I've opened https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11771 for improving the documentation. Note that in the next release you shouldn't have to set `MPIRUN_CMD`, that is a bug in the 1.18 release that has already been fixed upstream.